# Credit Card is not shown in PayPal Sandbox Payment Option After Login

Tags: cordova, paypal, ionic2, phonegap-plugins, paypal-sandbox

I am currently trying to add `PayPal` into my Ionic 2 application referring by referring to [this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/)

In PayPal Sandbox environment, I don't get why Credit Card is not shown in my PayPal payment options after I login with the sandbox buyer account.

**Here is my code to connect to PayPal:**

```
payViaPaypal() {
    let env = this;
    this.payPal.init({
        PayPalEnvironmentProduction: paypal.PayPalEnvironmentProduction,
        PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: paypal.PayPalEnvironmentSandbox
    }).then(() => {
        env.payPal.prepareToRender(paypal.CurrentEnvironment, new PayPalConfiguration({})).then(() => {
            let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'MYR', 'Description', 'sale');
            env.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((result) => {
                if (result.response.state == "approved") {
                    console.log("Success!")
                }
            }, () => {
                console.error('Error or render dialog closed without being successful');
            });
        }, () => {
            console.error('Error in configuration');
        });
    }, () => {
        console.error('Error in initialization, maybe PayPal isn\'t supported or something else');
    });
}
```

**Here is the screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the credit cards in this account are not showing is that I am **using MYR as currency in my PayPal Sandbox environment**. **In PayPal Sandbox environment, only USD is allowed for any credit card transaction**, otherwise, you will receive an error when you made credit card transaction using other currencies. Therefore, after I changed the currency to USD, everything works fine for me.